# Inserting a link into CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to insert a link into an instance of CKEditor using the following line: -

```
CKEDITOR.instances.CKInstance.insertHtml('<a href="http://www.example.com">My Text</a>');
```

All that happens though is that 'MyText' is inserted without the link. Anyone know how to insert the link properly?

PS. I know that CKEditor comes with a plugin to insert links but I'm doing my own one

Thanks
Shazoo

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. Is your CKInstance properly configured?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you're using CKEditor 4.1 or newer. And since you don't use the official link plugin, your editor discards all `<a>` tags. You need to properly configure [Allowed Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) so your editor accepts `<a>` tags back again.

You can do it when defining your command, like this:

```
// Assuming you want a dialog-driven command...
editor.addCommand( 'yourCommand', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'link', {
    allowedContent: 'a[!href]', // Allow <a> in the editor with mandatory href attr.
    requiredContent: 'a[href]' // This command requires <a> with href to be enabled.
} ) );
```

Or in editor's config with `config.extraAllowedContent = 'a[!href]'`. This is not recommended though as you develop a plugin (right?), which should bring a custom command.